# how to prevent converting date column to string in excel import

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-mvc, excel-dates

I'm using following code to import excel and read the file
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/upload-and-read-excel-file-in-mvc1

while getting data from date column it automatically converted to string.here this column is formatted as date in excel 
so if there is date '9/9/2019' im getting 43717

here is my minimal code:

```
for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)   
{
    var ex = new ExcelData();
    ex.CostCode = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value.ToString();
    ex.EmployeeNumber = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Value.ToString();
    ex.Class = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 3].Value.ToString();
    ex.Date = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 4].Value.ToString();
    ex.Hours = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 5].Value.ToString();
    ex.PayType = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 6].Value.ToString();
    dataList.Add(ex);  
}
```

for more code you can visit the above link.

Answer (score 0):

You must make converting string to DateTime...

> ex.Date = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 4].Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss");

```
for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)   
{
    var ex = new ExcelData();
    ex.CostCode = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value.ToString();
    ex.EmployeeNumber = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Value.ToString();
    ex.Class = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 3].Value.ToString();
    ex.Date = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 4].Value.ToString();
    ex.Hours = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 5].Value.ToString();
    ex.PayType = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 6].Value.ToString();
    dataList.Add(ex);  
}
```